# The bones don't attach to the mesh

Tags: mesh, armature, bones

I created this "astronauta", I created an armature and attached it with the "automatic height" function but the mesh doesn't move when I enter pose mode.

image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAr9L.png

this is the file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KRDiIxtDg7ZsqUJI5yvIXwdaAWklGU-k/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many bones don't have their "deform" option enalbled, and the armature is child of the mesh, while it should be the inverse.

To solve:

Select the armature and press Alt P (unparent, keep transformations).

In pose mode, select all bones, press the ALT button and while pressing Alt click on the deform bone option.

Then  in object mode select the mesh (first), shift select the armature, press Ctrl P, with automatic weights.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the ALT trick. I didn't know you could toggle Deform for multiple bones at once this way.

Comment: The ALT trick works for a lot of functions when more than one object are selected!

Comment: still not working ,this is the new link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KRDiIxtDg7ZsqUJI5yvIXwdaAWklGU-k/view?usp=sharing