# Bones won't attach to certain model/mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, armature, bones

I wanted to practice rigging so I grabbed a model I had downloaded and decided to go about trying to rig it.

I went through all the steps in this tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9dZjcFW3BRY I also tried the advice here. [The bones don't attach to the mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/214355/the-bones-dont-attach-to-the-mesh)

Nothing I can seem to do can attach the bones to the mesh. I've done everything I've seen listed to make sure the mesh is usable. Everything I try either the automatic weights option won't show up (It did in this file) or won't attach and move the model. I've been able to make it work on cubes, but any human shaped model won't seem to work.

This is the file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gZO5E2CQPEEIk1qQgiXtOrCqF3Vfm--p/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I cannot look at the file tonight, but… Refresher. The mesh object is parented to the armature object, so the mesh object as a whole will follow the armature object around. The deformation of the mesh is done by an Armature modifier on it, which can operate via mesh vertex groups with the same names as their corresponding bones, or via bone envelopes. All three of these steps can be done at once with the handy “Parent -> to armature deformation -> [multiple choice]” operators.

Comment: Same problem as [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/273304/107598). The mesh is completely flipped (inside out) for some reason. You need to flip all normals. The character looks like a game model. Game models often have a mesh split into parts for in-game customization. In Blender, the mesh parts result in duplicated vertices and in the infamous [Heat Weighting: Failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15964/107598) error. To merge the parts, switch to the *Edit* mode, select everything (key A) and do a Merge by Distance with key M.

Comment: Done this (^), you can parent the mesh to the armature with automatic weights.

Comment: @Blunder So this did work at first, I was busy but yesterday I got to test it and I did manage to do that and make it work. However the file didn't get saved I guess, and so I've both started over with a new file and used the one I uploaded, and even with the fix and looking at the link you gave, it's not working again, and sometimes it doesn't give me the option to do automatic weights, unless I try to parent it incorrectly, but even when I do that, (to test if I'm backwards) it still doesn't work now and I'm really confused.

Comment: The order of selection is important. The orange highlighted object is the *active* object. The red-colored objects are the *selected* objects. The *active* one is usually the last selected object in the viewport. (If you select objects in the outliner with the Shift key it's the first selected object). The *active* object becomes the parent, all *selected* objects will be children.

Comment: Consider that there should be a shoulder and an upper arm bone, and the hand bone should be aligned properly. But there is a very weird problem with the bones. If the arm is bent there are 2 verts sticking out for some reason. The weights look fine but the vertices show no reaction if you change the weights (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aY2R.jpg) The problem persists even if the mesh is completely remeshed. If I recreate the bones it works (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGNSx.jpg) I have no idea what causes this weird problem.